# Standard Kleene algebras --- Precise definition and categorical interpretation

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, soft-question, automata

On page 27 of Conway's book ``Regular Algebra and Finite Machines'', a **Standard Kleene Algebra** is defined rather loosely as

[image: 1]

It seems that the $\sum$ operation is in reality a collection of operations: for every set $T$ a map $\sum_T:S^T\to S$ that takes a family of Elements $\mathbf{E}=(E_t)_{t\in T}$ to an element $\sum_T\mathbf{E}\in S$, alternatively written as $\sum_{t\in T}E_t$ and subject to some implicit assumptions (such as invariance under permutation of the indices and $\sum_\emptyset\emptyset=0$).

I find this somewhat unsatisfying. It seems that one should (?) alternatively define a single operation $\sum:2^S\to S,A\mapsto\sum_A$ (and to allow the notation $\sum_A = \sum_{a\in A}a$) such that

1. $\sum_\emptyset=0$
2. $\sum_{\{s\}}=s$ for all $s\in S$
3. for any set $\mathcal{A}\subset 2^S$, setting $\bigcup\mathcal{A}=\bigcup_{A\in\mathcal{A}}A\in 2^S$ and $\sum_\mathcal{A}=\{\sum_A\mid A\in\mathcal{A}\}\in 2^S$, $$\sum{}_{\bigcup\mathcal{A}} = \sum{}_{\sum_\mathcal{A}}$$
4. For $A, B\in 2^S$, setting $A\cdot B=\{a\cdot b\mid a\in A, b\in B\}\in 2^S$, $$\sum{}_{A}\cdot\sum{}_{B}=\sum{}_{A\cdot B}$$

And then define, for any set $T$ and any family $\mathbf{E}=(E_t)_{t\in T}\in S^T$, $\sum_T\mathbf{E}=\sum_{t\in T}E_t := \sum_{\mathrm{Ran}(\mathbf{E})}$ where $\mathrm{Ran}(\mathbf{E})=\{E_t\mid t\in T\}$

> **Question 1.** Is there an advantage to Conway's formulation of the axiomatics of Standard Kleene Algebras over the above ?

Points 2. and 3. mean that the map $\sum:2^S\to S$ makes $S$ an algebra over the powerset monad (which isn't surprising since one of the early propositions in Conway's text is that $S$ is a complete lattice)

> **Question 2.** What is the categorical interpretation of multiplication $\cdot$ and of the Kleene star operator $*$ ?
>
> **Question 3.** More broadly, is there a neat categorical definition of Standard Kleene Algebras that may make sense in other categories than $\textbf{Set}$? Is there a good source on this point of view?

With respect to question 3 I only have vague guesses. Since Conway's S3 and S4 mean that $(S,\cdot)$ is a monoid, S5 is a compatibility condition with the powerset-monad algebra structure $\sum$. It seems that the star construction is then a sort of ``free monoid construction within $(S,\sum)$'', if that makes any sense.

Comment: On (3), I think that if you think of $\Sigma$ as the operation of taking coproducts (possibly infinite), $0$ as the coproduct unit, $\cdot$ as a monoidal/tensor product, and $1$ as the tensor unit, then S1-S5 look like they make a lot of sense. (Some equations should be replaced with commutative diagrams). One can then consider monoid/algebra objects in such a category, and the Kleene star of an object should be the “free” monoid object. Applied to sets with the categorical product we get monoids as the monoid objects, and the free monoid on a set as the Kleene star.

Comment: Applied to the category of vector spaces over a fixed field with the tensor product, algebras over that field are the monoid objects, and the Kleene star is the tensor algebra of a vector space (the free algebra in the proper sense).